# Partition over or Group By best for Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  P.FirstName, d.Name, EDH.StartDate
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department d
ON EDH.DepartmentID=D.DepartmentID
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee e
ON EDH.BusinessEntityID=E.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Person.Person P
ON E.BusinessEntityID=P.BusinessEntityID
WHERE EndDate IS NULL 
ORDER BY D.NAME;
```

I am trying to list the person in each department that has worked there the longest. I know that using the top(1) for each department would most likely be the best option but I can figure if using partition or group by is going to be the better option in this case. Anybody with more skill than me have any ideas?

Comment: `WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department ORDER BY timeofworking DESC) rnk FROM ... ) SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rnk=1`

Comment: more [detailed "hint"](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104&m=0)

Answer (score 0):

Working the longest means the earliest start date.  That suggests:

```
SELECT ed.*
FROM (SELECT P.FirstName, d.Name, EDH.StartDate,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY D.DepartmentID ORDER BY EDH.StartDate) as seqnum
      FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh JOIN 
           HumanResources.Department d
           ON EDH.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID JOIN
           HumanResources.Employee e
           ON EDH.BusinessEntityID = E.BusinessEntityID JOIN
           Person.Person P
           ON E.BusinessEntityID = P.BusinessEntityID
      WHERE EndDate IS NULL
     ) ed
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY D.NAME;
```